# How to add Long Texts below footers for different cms pages in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, seo

I want to put text after the footer links for SEO purposes for my Magento website. I want different texts to be shown below the footer for the homepage, categories and the products.

As an example, you can refer to this: https://www.mybatua.com/ [They have a long 800-word text below the footer for their home and categories.]

I tried using the widget and static block approach but the text never shows when I select page footer as the location.

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

the static block approach in this case seems to be a good approach.

1) Create 3 blocks : `seo_footer_homepage`, `seo_footer_categories` and `seo_footer_products`.

2) If you don't have already one, create a file called `local.xml` in your theme (`app/design/frontend/<your-theme>/default/layout/local.xml`) with the following content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <cms_index_index>
        <reference name="footer">
             <block type="cms/block" name="seo_footer_homepage" as="seo_footer_homepage" after="-">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>seo_footer_homepage</block_id</action>
             </block>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
    <catalog_category_view>
        <reference name="footer">
             <block type="cms/block" name="seo_footer_categories" as="seo_footer_categories" after="-">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>seo_footer_categories</block_id</action>
             </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="footer">
             <block type="cms/block" name="seo_footer_products" as="seo_footer_products" after="-">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>seo_footer_products</block_id</action>
             </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Comment: Hi Julien. It didn't work. I added the lines as suggested and some content to the static blocks too but with no results on the frontend.

Comment: Well, it's weird : I guess you have some specifics code (or my code is wrong..., who knows). For example : the handle `cms_index_index`  is the standard handle for the home. Maybe you should try to debug with some `Mage::log($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());` (you will see which handle are available in each pages (home, product, category). Then, you should look if the `reference name="footer"` is good for you (Maybe this reference has been removed and/or you are using another reference for the footer part).

Comment: cms_index_index is the standard handle as you said. Could you please tell me where should i write that code to check the handles? I have less knowledge and i am still learning.
i changed the reference name="footer" to "footer_links" and the links disappeared but the content did not show below that block.

Comment: You should write it in a template that is called on every page. It depends on your code but, for example, in `app/design/frontend/base-or-your-theme/default/template/page/html/head.phtml`. Then, ensure that you have enabled the logs (`System->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Log Settings`) and look in the `system.log` file.

Comment: You were right Julien. I added the lines under cms_index_index for the homepage. Just had to add a few extra lines in app-design-frontend-tem-template-page-html-**bold**footer.phtml**bold** :

`<?php if (Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()):?>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('seo_footer_homepage')->toHtml();?> 
<?php endif?>`

But there seems to be an issue that the text is not aligned as per the page. It is running into the corners and stretching on the screen. Any solutions for that?

Comment: It is strange that you have to add `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('seo_footer_homepage')->toHtml();?>`. If you look in the standard `footer.phtml` (I mean `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/footer.phtml`), you should see : `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>` : that means that every childs of the reference `footer` will be rendered (and we have defined `seo_footer_homepage` as a child of footer)

Comment: I checked the base file and it does have the code as you say but if I do not use `<?php if (Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()):?> <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('seo_footer_homepage')->toHtml();?> <?php endif?>`, the block never appears on the homepage. If i change the `<reference name="content">` then the block appears above the footer even after using `before,after` tags

Comment: FYI, it is normal that every child of the reference content appears without doing anything in the template (because the type of the content block is `core/text_list`).  At least, a `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('seo_footer_homepage') ?>` in the footer template should render your block too. In your footer template (not the one one in the base theme), do you have the `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>` too ?

Comment: I tried using `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('seo_footer_homepage') ?>` but the block is displayed on all pages then. 
No, i am not using this `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>`

Comment: Ok, I see : if the block appears in all pages, that means that you have declared the `seo_footer_homepage`  not only in the `cms_index_index` handle as I suggested (maybe in the `default` handle ?). And it is normal that no child of the footer are rendered (until you write `$this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->...->toHtml()`) if there is no `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>` in the footer template.

Comment: No. i declared `seo_footer_homepage` in the `cms_index_index` Only.

But there is another issue for other pages. In case of categories, i wanted to use different blocks for different categories. But the above method is showing just 1 block for all the categories. How should i define them separately for each category?

Comment: Well, a different block for each category requires maybe a different approach.  There is an handle for each category but it depends on the the Id of it : so it's not a good idea (in my opinion) to use it in your code (as the id of category may vary on different environment). For your need, I suggest you to do it in the admin : in each category you want, you can edit the  `Custom Layout Update` in the `Custom Design` tab. Another way should be to create a new attribute for categories (that will be related to cms block) : but it is more complicated.

Comment: Could you assist me in the `Custom Layout Update` approach in the Custom Design tab?

Comment: Unfortunatly, i have no time for doing a chat with you. Updating layout in the admin is not very different from editing the layout in xml files : you have to find the reference you want to update and then, add your block in it. For example, see https://www.jimcode.org/2011/06/layout-update-xml-magento/ . Good luck !